# css: бегущий градиент

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, градиент

подскажите, можно ли вообще с помощью css реализовать бегущий градиент, чтобы создать имитацию отблеска на элементе

т.е.

1) есть `div` заданных размеров и однородной закраски фона `background`

2) при наведении мышки фон меняется на градиентный

3) градиентный фон смещается с начала элемента до конца элемента (светлая линия проходит от начала элемента до конца элемента)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во Flash это делалось легко - рисовался элемент с градиентом, маска и элемент перемещался под маской.

А можно ли с помощью css сделать такой же эффект (по сути просто изменить положение максимума градиента)

P.S.

Только без использования Javascript, с помощью одной CSS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как-то так

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.gradient{
  background-color:#cda;
  min-height:100vw;
  transition:all .2s ease;
}
.gradient:hover{
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#acd, #fff 30px, #acd 60px) no-repeat -100px 0/100px 100%, #acd;
  animation:move 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move{
  from{
    background-position:-100px 0;
  }
  to{
    background-position:120% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: то что надо, спасибо!
Дальше напильником докручу

Comment: смущает только, что рывками идет

Comment: Теперь не дёргается

Comment: просто более точно задали начало и конец анимации?
сделал (когда допиливал) тоже самое - вроде стало без рывков

`@keyframes move{
 from {
  background-position-x: -45px;
 }
 to {
  background-position-x: 175px;
 }
}`

Comment: Не только, градиент теперь отрисовывается на участке шириной 100px. Остальной фон заливается просто цветом. Так затрачивается меньше ресурсов на отрисовку + можно использовать `%` в `background-position`

Comment: @zhurof хороший, полезный ответ. Отвечай почаще :)